# Ubuntu 16.04 window switcher not appearing

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text

I'm finding that on Ubuntu 16.04 when I do alt-tab to bring up the window switcher, sometimes this is not visible, and appears to be stuck behind the windows I have open.

Anyone else experienced this glitch? Any suggestions?

[See screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmIeq.png)

Comment: Should say that I've only noticed this in workspaces where sublime text 3126 is, or has recently been, open. I'm wondering if its related at all to this problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314696/alt-tab-menu-not-showing-when-in-fullscreen

Comment: It looks like you've been playing with your compiz settings to me, might wanna check that and tell us what you did.

Comment: Hi xangua. Actually I have not (deliberately) changed any compiz settings. Is it possible this could have happened without my explicit asking? (Eg software installation)?

Answer (score 0):

To fiz this add the simple full screen setting to the Sublime User Settings with:

```
"use_simple_full_screen": true
```